# Does C# offer a compile-time way to refactor code based on annotations?

Tags: c#, .net, automated-refactoring

I haven't written much in C# yet, primarily writing in C++, so I was wondering if C# offers a way to let you instruct the compiler to refactor code at compile-time based on an annotation?

Basically I'm looking for a way to let the compiler automatically wrap every non-blacklisted class variable in a custom wrapper class with assignment and conversion operators for the wrapped type. So instead of `public CustomWrapper<int> someInt;` you simply use `public int someInt;` as a regular integer and the compiler refactors the code if the class is annotated with the corresponding annotation.

To prevent some quick remarks, the custom wrapper is non-trivial.

Comment: " you simply use `public int someInt;`" - what about usages of someInt? - `int` and `CustomWrapper<int>` are very different in many aspects. things which compiled and worked for int, will likely get broken for wrapper

Comment: @ASh i think what the author is trying to say is features of C++ like `constexpr` and `typedef`which are executed at compile time, exist in C#?

Comment: @ASh I'm aware of the type incompatibility, that's why I also mentioned the operators. ```public static implicit operator T(CustomWrapper<T> w)``` and ```public static implicit operator CustomWrapper<T>(T t)``` (something along those lines) _should_ solve any useage problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not built into C# or even .NET. What you are looking for are IL rewriting tools or [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) tools. These are all applied *after* the code is compiled. Take a look at

- [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) - "Extensible tool for weaving .net assemblies"
- [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) - an AOP code weaver (commercial)

Here's an [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/453065/ILRewriting-for-beginners) to aid you for rolling your own.

If you must or want to do some complex refactoring prior to compiling, you can [write a custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) Rosyln [code analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019) and corresponding code fix. This makes it semi-automatic; if you apply the suggestion as you code, the code can be transformed according to the code-fix.

Comment: Thank you! Though it's somewhat unfortunate in respect of the usablility of the concept I'm testing. I was positive there are ways to accomplish this at compile-time and completely checked by the compiler. Apparently I was wrong ..